# Get the calculated position in pixels of a background image

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I've seen variation of this question on Stackoverflow that do not answer the question.

The problem is that the background image is placed using % or center, left, top, etc. But what we actually want to know is what that positioning is calculated at in pixels. I'm not asking what it is set at in the CSS, inline style or otherwise, but what the browser has calculated the position should be based upon those style settings.

In other words, if a div is 100px wide, and we tell the background image to be 10% from the left. I want javascript to return 10 pixels, not 10%.

Please no JQuery or other libraries, just pure javascript, html and DOM.

I've already looked at:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

I would like something like this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect
... But for background image/s.

Those functions are as far as I've got so far looking for a solution. We have also tried getting Node properties, but we're still experimenting with that.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes I've been playing with calculating it myself using the available information. But its not giving perfect results. The returned numbers do not match exactly the measured pixels when a screenshot is taken and measured in photoshop. Its close, but not exact. Hence I want the numbers the browser is calculating. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to query the computed background position directly, but you should be able to calculate it based on the dimensions of the image and its container.

I ran into this exact situation yesterday (which is how I came across this question). I wanted to know the computed vertical position, in pixels, for a background image with the following conditions:

- Dimensions of `1198` x `2246`
- Positioned at `center bottom`
- Inside a container (`<header>`) that's `600px` tall and `100%` width
- Sized to `cover`

I came up with the following formula:

```
var headerHeight = $("header").height(),
    headerWidth = $("header").width(),
    bgHeight = Math.round(headerWidth / 0.5333),
    bgBottom = headerHeight - bgHeight;
```

For `bgHeight`, I divide the width of the container by `0.5333` since that's the aspect ratio of the source image (`1198` / `2246`), then round it to the nearest whole number.

So if my browser window is, for example, `1280px` wide:

- `headerHeight` = `600`
- `headerWidth` = `1280`
- `bgHeight` = (`1280` / `0.5333`) = `2400`
- `bgBottom` = `600` - `2400` = `-1800`

So the pixel value of the background image's vertical position is `-1800px`.